# Process a queue with parallel/async requests

Tags: python, request

I want to implement a parallel `request.get()` function, that processes a queue of requests and puts the result in a list, which, when finished, is processed by a standard sequential code. I tried the following, but my code doesn´t end and does not print the IDs.

```
import requests
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

BASE = 'http://www.uniprot.org'
KB_ENDPOINT = '/uniprot/'
FORMAT = ".xml"

num_threads = 10

ID_q = Queue()
ID_data = Queue()

# worker function
def get_ID_data(ID_q, ID_data, BASE, KB_ENDPOINT, FORMAT):
    while True:
        ID = ID_q.get()
        print(ID)
        ID_data.put(requests.get(BASE + KB_ENDPOINT + ID + FORMAT))
        ID_q.task_done()
        ID_data.task_done()

# initialize worker
for i in range(num_threads):
    worker = Thread(target=get_ID_data, args=(ID_q, ID_data, BASE, KB_ENDPOINT, FORMAT))
    worker.setDaemon(True)
    worker.start()

# load IDs and put in queue
ID_list = ["A6ZMA9", "N1P5E6",
       "H0GM11", "H0GZ91",
       "A0A0L8VK54", "G2WKA0",
       "C8ZEQ4", "B5VPH8",
       "B3LLU5", "C7GL72",
       "J8QFS9", "J8Q1C1",
       "A0A0L8RDV1"]

for ID in ID_list:
    ID_q.put(ID)

ID_q.join()

# work with ID_data
print(ID_data)
```

Update:
I changed @pkqxdd answer using asyncio and aiohttp to this:

```
import asyncio,aiohttp

IDs = ["A6ZMA9", "N1P5E6",
       "H0GM11", "H0GZ91",
       "A0A0L8VK54", "G2WKA0",
       "C8ZEQ4", "B5VPH8",
       "B3LLU5", "C7GL72",
       "J8QFS9", "J8Q1C1",
       "A0A0L8RDV1"]

BASE = 'http://www.uniprot.org'
KB_ENDPOINT = '/uniprot/'
FORMAT = ".xml"

async def get_data_coroutine(session, ID):
    async with session.get(BASE + KB_ENDPOINT + ID + FORMAT) as response:
        res = await response.text()
        print(ID)
        if not res:
            raise NameError('{} is not available'.format(ID))
        return res

async def main(loop): 
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as session:
        tasks = [get_data_coroutine(session, ID) for ID in IDs]
        return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result = loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've mentioned async, I'm assuming you are using Python3.6 or higher.

The library `requests` doesn't really support async programming and it's kinda a dead end trying to make it async. A better idea is to use `aiohttp` instead.

You can achieve your goal with simple codes like this:

```
import asyncio,aiohttp

BASE = 'http://www.uniprot.org'
KB_ENDPOINT = '/uniprot/'
FORMAT = ".xml"

ID_list = ["A6ZMA9", "N1P5E6",
       "H0GM11", "H0GZ91",
       "A0A0L8VK54", "G2WKA0",
       "C8ZEQ4", "B5VPH8",
       "B3LLU5", "C7GL72",
       "J8QFS9", "J8Q1C1",
       "A0A0L8RDV1"]

session=aiohttp.ClientSession()
async def get_data(ID):
    async with session.get(BASE + KB_ENDPOINT + ID + FORMAT) as response:
        return await response.text()

coros=[]
for ID in ID_list:
    coros.append(get_data(ID))

loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
fut=asyncio.gather(*coros)
loop.run_until_complete(fut)
print(fut.result())
```

(Yes, I see the warning. But I don't really want to make the answer more complicated. You should change it to suit your purpose better.)

Comment: This code gives me the error: RuntimeError: This event loop is already running

Comment: @Benni were you calling from jupyter by any chance?